# Как вызвать функцию на Bash внутри аргумента команды?

Tags: bash

Как мне вызвать функцию на Bash внутри аргумента команды ?

Есть вот такая система директорий:

```
Aircrack-NG_scripts
|
+--+-system
|  |
|  +----Wifi_get-interface.sh
|
+----Wifi_Normal-Mode.sh
```

В файле Wifi_get-interface.sh, который в директории system, находится вот такой код:

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_interface {
    read -p 'Wifi Interface: ' interface
    return $interface
}


function get_mon_interface {
    get_interface
    mon_interface="${interface}mon"
    return $mon_interface
}

export -f get_interface
export -f get_mon_interface
```

А в файле Wifi_Normal-Mode.sh вот такой:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./system/Wifi_get-interface.sh

./system/Wifi_get-interface.sh

airmon-ng stop get_mon_interface
service network-manager start
```

Когда я выполняю Bash сценарий Wifi_Normal-Mode.sh Aircrack-NG говорит, что интерфейс `get_mon_interface` не найден. Мне нужно, что когда Bash сценарий Wifi_Normal-Mode.sh выполнялся, он брал функцию из файла Wifi_get-interface.sh, который в директории system и чтоб выполнял эту функцию в команде sudo airmon-ng stop get_mon_interface.

Как исправить?

Comment: для начала уберите вызовы программы sudo и запускайте сам скрипт с административными привилегиями.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Но как тогда выполнять функции внутри команд ?

Comment: я не понимаю, что такое функции внутри команд.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Чтоб когда выполнялась команда "airmon-ng stop get_mon_interface" выполнялась функция get_mon_interface которая находится в файле Wifi_get-interface.sh который лежит в директории system. Но на данный момент это вызовет ошибку. Как сделать чтоб выполнялась функция get_mon_interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас тут две проблемы - функцию надо вызывать в контексте вызова `$()`, а сама функция может возвращать только код завершения (целое число то бишь), так что строку придется печатать. Как-то так:

```
function foo
{
        read -p "Wifi Interface: " interface
        echo "${interface}"
}

echo "$(foo)"
```

в этом примере `"$(foo)"` заменится на результат `echo "${interface}"`